# what does "in wide sense" mean?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I came across the statement "the sequence increases(in wide sense)".

So my doubt is what does author mean by wide sense?I came across this in number theory book

Comment: It probably means the author is French ("au sense large" means "weakly").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence increases in wide sense means that it is not strictly increasing ( $a_n>a_{n-1})$ but it is non-decreasing $a_n\geq a_{n-1}$